# \brokenpenalty on odd page only

Tags: typography, hyphenation

Can I set `\brokenpenalty=10000` for **odd** page only?
(for prevent hyphenation from odd to even page. Not from even to odd).
Should I use `everypage` or `atbegshi`?

Comment: in general you can not do this: the value is set per paragraph and you don't know which page or pages the text will fall on at the point that the settings need to be made. (The paragraph may be more than one page, of a figure may be inserted and push this text to the next page or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true but with normal documents the assumption that a paragraph is less than a page is reasonable. And if the assumption fails then the worst that happens is that for one page the algorithm makes its decision with wrong data.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use `everypage` and write:

```
\AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifodd\c@page%
      \global\brokenpenalty=110%
    \else%
      \global\brokenpenalty=10000%
    \fi%
}
```

You may also need to use `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` to get access to `\c@page`.